# System.Threading.ThreadStateException

Tags: c#

I am running a thread like this:

instance variable

```
private Thread workerThread = null;
```

in contructor

```
workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.remoteRequestBackgroundTask));
```

in a method, I start the thread

```
    private void btnTransferData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////Start the thread
        workerThread.Start();
        //remoteRequestBackgroundTask();
    }
```

remoteRequestBackgroundTask

```
    private void remoteRequestBackgroundTask()
    {
      //does some background processing and then finishes
     }
```

This works the first time I run the Thread, however, when it finishes and I run it again, I get "System.Threading.ThreadStateException".  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create the worker thread in the constructor.  You should move this code into the btnTransferData_Click method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the you're creating a new Thread every time you call btnTransferData_Click (as in, the click isn't called twice for the same instance)?

looking [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstateexception.aspx) It seems that this can be caused when you call a Thread again after it's already been executed. Create the thread in the Click method (instead of in the constructor) to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the thread has executed. You cannot "restart" it. For this example, the solution is to create a new thread and run that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse a `Thread` instance after it has been used.  You would need to create a new `Thread` instance to be able to run it again.

However seeing as you are probably writing a WinForms application , you should use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class instead.  At least with this, you can reuse the worker instance as many times as you need it.